# Как сделать отступы между полями ввода?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать отступы между полями ввода (там где красным помечено)?
Знаю что есть какой-то тэг в html, который можно тупо между элементами прописать, но не могу его вспомнить. Он вроде даже не закрывающийся.

Comment: <br>, чтобы не усложнять....

Comment: Благодарствую!!!

Comment: br не самое лучшее решение

Comment: вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/kxvpduLu/

Comment: А ты можешь скинуть свою разметку блоков?
Но как вариант я бы добавил дополнительный класс для правого или левого input'а сделал бы ему margin-lefr или margin-right соответственно, а если отступ нужен внизу, сделал бы как писал easy_peasy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавь свои `input`ы в блок, например, `someDiv`

HTML:

```
<div class="someDiv">
   <input type="text" id="1" />
   <input type="text" id="2" />
<div>
```

И напиши `CSS` для блока `someDiv`:

```
.someDiv {
   margin-bottom: 20px; //Или любое значение, которое тебе необходимо
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Стандартные свойства `margin` не помогают в решении этого вопроса?

```
margin-right: 10px
```

Comment: хочется не усложнять

Comment: Хотя можно и с margin. А не подскажите как сделать отступ между двумя верхними строками?

Comment: margin-right: 10px;

Comment: А как правильно рассчитывать расстояние? От точки центра полукруга или от  краёв?

Comment: От краёв я измерил 22 px в макете в фотошопе. Сделал margin-right: 22px, но получилось значительно больше.

Comment: От краев, это прямоугольник с загругленными краями, но прямоугольником он от этого быть не перестал :)

Comment: Тогда всё-таки почему расстояние за большое? Может в бутстрапе какие-то свойства по умолчанию прописаны?

Comment: Хотя, вроде-бы всё нормально. Меня просто наверное глючит.