# Вылезают строки

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Вылезают строки. Появляется полоса прокрутки снизу.
Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#text form #inputFirstName,
#inputEmailAddress {
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 350px;
}
#text form #inputFirstName {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#text form #inputMessage {
  max-width: 720px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#text h1 {
  position: center;
  padding-top: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>...</h1>
    <p>...</p>
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inputFirstName">First Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name">

        <label class="sr-only" for="inputEmailAddress">Email Address</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputEmailAddress" placeholder="Email Address">
      </div>
    </form>

    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inputMessage">Message...</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputMessage" placeholder="Message...">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Верстаю на бутсрапе.

Comment: Горизонтальная прокрутка при ширине 320 пикселей? Ничего, что у вас ширина объявлена 350?

Comment: Это ширина строки

Comment: Двух строк этих

Comment: Она должны быть по 350 в ширину.

Comment: Вы прямо прибиваете гвоздями точные значения для элементов. Зачем? В бутстрапе хороша сетка под разные разрешения.

Comment: Так как же всё-таки сделать эти строки адаптивными?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `px` используй `%` для задания `width`, так как ты нацелен на создание адаптивного сайта с `bootstrap`. `CSS`:

```
#inputFirstName, #inputMessage {
   width: 100%;
   //OR
   width: 80%;
   margin-left: 10%;
}
```

И лучше всего из `bootstrap` использовать только сетку. imho

Comment: они не должны растягиваться во весь экран.

Comment: когда он большой.

Comment: @Ravdan все верно, он берет 100% от текущей ширины блока. Попробуй.

Comment: @Ravdan если вы хотите использовать ширину 350px, то для экранов менее 350px вы не сможете убрать горизонтальный скролл безболезненно для внешнего вида вашего сайта.

Comment: Получилось! Но при этом почему-то две верхние строки начали накладываться одна на другую при широком экране. Должно быть так:
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/551696/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/551731#551731

Comment: Ничего не понимаю

Comment: Вот css если что:
#text form #inputFirstName, #inputEmailAddress {
 border-radius: 25px;
 height: 50px;
 max-width: 350px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 width: 100%;
}

Comment: @Ravdan Ну если у вас 2 inputa в одной строке задайте ширину для каждого элемента 50% или менее и все будет окей.

Comment: #text form #inputFirstName, #inputEmailAddress {
 border-radius: 25px;
 height: 50px;
 max-width: 350px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 width: 100%;
}

#text form #inputFirstName {
 width: 50%;
}

#text form #inputEmailAddress {
 width: 50%;
}


То есть вот так?

Comment: @Ravdan Да, вроде все верно.

Comment: Не получилось. Вроде бы сами инпуты только уменьшились и всё.

Comment: наполовину ......

Comment: @Ravdan Я не понимаю. Вам же нужно чтобы 2 inputа было в строку и чтобы ширина их была во всю ширину вне зависимости от разрешения экрана? Верно?

Comment: на больших экранах эти 2 inputa должны быть по 350px

Comment: в одну строку конечно же

Comment: а на маленьких в 2, плюс адаптивными

Comment: @Ravdan Ну добавьте к width:50%; еще max-width: 350px;

Comment: так оно у меня здесь #text form #inputFirstName, #inputEmailAddress {
 border-radius: 25px;
 height: 50px;
 max-width: 350px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 width: 100%;
}

Смотрите выше

Comment: Короче говоря, после изменения width: 350px на width: 100% появилась адаптивность строк, но они перестали идти в одну линию на больших экранах.